# Stopping ng-map stores previous street view

Tags: angularjs, ng-map

I have an ng-map issue when I follow the steps -

> Load map
>   Drop the streetview person on map
>   Return to map
>   Place streetview in a different location

At the final step Streetview initially shows the previous location before  the new location

You can see the problem at https://ngmap.github.io/ which runs this code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ngMap">
<head>
<title>Simle Map</title>
<meta name="description" content="Simple Map">
<meta name="keywords" content="ng-map,AngularJS,center">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<script src="script-tags-for-development.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <ng-map center="[40.74, -74.18]"></ng-map>
</body>
</html>
```

Can I prevent streetview showing the previous location?